# Trying to build Boost with gcc toolchain

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, boost, mingw

For some reason when I try to run b2 with toolset=gcc I get the following.

```
C:\boost_1_49_0>.\b2.exe toolset=gcc
C:/boost_1_49_0/tools/build/v2/tools\gcc.jam:129: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: no command provided, default command 'g++' not found
error: initialized from
C:/boost_1_49_0/tools/build/v2/build\toolset.jam:38: in toolset.using from modul
e toolset
C:/boost_1_49_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:481: in process-explicit-toolset
-requests from module build-system
C:/boost_1_49_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:562: in load from module build-s
ystem
C:\boost_1_49_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in import from module mod
ules
C:\boost_1_49_0\tools\build\v2\kernel\bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from mod
ule
C:\boost_1_49_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I had to add C:\MinGW\bin to my Path environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. What did you have to do to get it to look like that?

Comment: Ahh cool. Thanks for the post and sorry I neglected to see it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run this command in a command line which can access mingw/cygwin bin directory. I mean when you type g++ it works and doesn't return command not found. If you are using mingw or cygwin they have dedicated command lines which g++ (bin directory) paths are registered in environment variables. Of course you can use Eclipse for compiling your c++ apps under windows.

Comment: I run b2 by using

     cd C:/boost_1_49_0
     .\b2.exe toolset=gcc

Comment: Try to add C:\MinGW\bin to PATH environment variable in Windows.

Comment: I added it with a comma. Is that how you do this? 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\java.exe, C:\MinGW\bin

Comment: No, you should use a ; I think. There are a lot of paths there separating with ;.

Comment: Adding something to Windows Env. var. "PATH" : `PATH <YOUR_FULL_PATH>;%PATH%` - this will keep the original PATH and just adds another path of yours :)

Answer (score 0):

You are building Boost with gcc toolset on a Windows Machine (Cygwin, MinGW)?
The main problem here is that the Boost build system can not find your compiler. Make sure g++ is in your path.

Comment: I have MinGW (C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe) is this what you mean?

Comment: Try doing this from your console before starting b2: set PATH=%PATH%;c:\MinGW\bin\